# Perl подключение по ssh использую Net::OpenSSH (или другим способом)

Tags: perl, ssh

Использую ActivePerl 5.22 под Windows. И к сожалению в менеджере пакетов нет доступного пакета `Net::SSH::Perl`, есть только `Net::OpenSSH` и `Net::SSH`.
Как я понял `Net::SSH` использует непосредственно командную строку, где в виндовс естественно нет ssh клиента. 
В `Net::OpenSSH` я пытался подключиться по примерам в интернете:

```
my $ssh2 = Net::OpenSSH->new("".$user.":".$password."@".$host.":22");
$ssh->error and die "Cannot open the connection " . $ssh->error;
```

Но по неизвестным мне причинам он даже не пытается подключиться и при этом скрипт просто на глухо зависает и его не остановить через `CTRL+C`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня может зависать скрипт который подключается через OpenSSH или какой библиотекой можно воспользоваться для подключения в Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не баг, это фича ( Вот тут http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.62/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm так и написано: "On the other hand, Net::OpenSSH does not work on Windows, not even under Cygwin.".

Когда мне нужно было под виндовсом работать по ssh, я использовал WinSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:ru). Ему можно скормить текстовый файл с командами, а он сконектится и сделает все что там написано.

Comment: Большое спасибо, воспользуюсь вашим советом. Даж под убунту эта `Net::SSH::Perl` библиотека не захотела ставиться, щас на Debian поэксперементирую еще.